# WPF MVVM Is it possible to refresh screen, so it load again?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi I would like to refresh/reload the View, not only the datacontext but everything. I've tried to  call those 2 from controller but nothing happens:

```
UpdateLayout()

InvalidateVisual()
```

The reason for this is that I have few properties which are OneTime Mode and I would like to refresh them after the screen been saved.

Comment: What about closing it and opening it again?

Comment: **The reason for this is that I have few properties which are OneTime Mode and I would like to refresh them after the screen been saved.**  so your poperty is not `OneTime`, `OneWay`maybe?

Comment: The problem is that one property is related to the other and If I do OneWay, the property change when user didn't save the screen yet. I want this properties only change when screen is saved. I could probably do another property screen saved and then update it if both property change, but I would prefer to reload screen.

Comment: @Whistler you should do what you say at the end of your previous comment "I could probably do another property screen saved".  With a second property on the viewmodel it is entirely within your control, and is also unit testable, i.e. perform update, verify that it has not changed yet, now save, and verify that it has changed

Answer (score 1):

OneTime properties do exactly that - They fetch their values once. If you want to trigger your updates at a particular time, then you should raise NotifyPropertyChanged for those properties at that time. If you do not want them updating every time they change, then you should not raise the event when changing the property, only when you wish the value to be updated.

However, this sounds to me like you should be using some layer of abstraction to handle this saving idea you're using, and then calculate and update those fields. If they're on a separate view (whether that's a different control, or window, or dialog, or whatever), they should *not* share a ViewModel (or, in ASP, controller). Instead, they should pass the information back and forth, or be synchronized to the business object you're operating on, and only update the UI when in a viewable state.